# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found error while using instruments

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4

I'm getting the classic "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found" when I use instruments to try and profile my app. When I try to build, run, debug, distribute, my app, I don't get this problem at all. Has anyone experience this problem before?

Comment: @MichelePercich I did this and changed it from Release to Debug and it worked. Thanks! Do you want to put it up as an answer?

Comment: Profiling with a Debug configuration is worthless, as those are compiled without any compiler-optimizations.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Edit Schemes... check the Building Configuration under the Profile scheme. Be sure that a valid provisioning profile is set for that building configuration.

Comment: I have the same trouble. Could you say how to fix it in xcode 7?

Comment: It should be Product -> Scheme -> Profile -> Info -> Build Configuration